# Fetch dropdown data from db in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, html-select, dropdown

I want design a login web page in jsp, which consist user type dropdown, user name and password field.
The dropdown values has to fetch from database. I don't know how to fetch these values please help me.

**thank you**

Comment: Can you post something that you have tried? You will greatly increase the chance of getting answers.

Comment: There are many in stackoverflow for your expectation. Have you checked similar question links right side of your post?